# How to clustering multiple images by the name in python

Tags: python, image, cluster-analysis, data-science

I have a multiple types of images in one folder and i want to save each type of Images in a different variable by the name and the first 6 character of the name is same and the primly character is the 7th.

i know how to import the images but my issue is how to separate it, and display them in the same time.

```
import cv2
import glop

image = [cv2.imread(img)for img in glop.glop ("c:/B/*.png")]
```

---

**e.g :**

sa_01_**D**F001 "D Type",

sa_01_**D**F002 "D Type",

sa_01_**N**B001 "N Type",

sa_01_**N**B002 "N Type",

sa_01_**K**P001 "K Type",

sa_01_**K**P002 "K Type".

### To summarize my problem :

- Separate the image by the name.
- Save each type into variable.
- Display multiple image in same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the answers, i solve my issue by this :

```
import cv2
import glob
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation,Dropout,Flatten,Dense
import numpy
import os

seed = 10
numpy.random.seed(seed)
image_b = [cv2.imread(file_b)for file_b in glob.glob ("C:/BC/BENI/*.png")]
labels = [name[name.find("_") + 1 : name.find("-")] 
for name in glob.glob ("C:/BC/BENI/*.png")]
labeled_images = list(zip(image_b, labels))
all_image =('image_b')
X = all_image[:] 
Y = all_image[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using a dictionary

```py
    import cv2
    import glob

    same_characters = 6 #number of characters that define if two images are in the same group / type
    image_dict = {img : [cv2.imread(img)] for img in glob.glob("c:/B/*.png")}



    for key in image_dict:
        group = key.split('_')[2][0]
        image_dict[key].append(group)

    for key in image_dict:
        print("Image name = \"",key,"\" => ",image_dict[key][0], ", group =\"" + image_dict[key][1] + "\"")

        cv2.imshow(key, image_dict[key]) #show the image, don't use it when you're reading too many pictures
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The keys of the dictionary will be the image name. For each key there is a list where image_dict[name_of_image][0] is the image itself, image_dict[name_of_image][1] is the group

**Edit**

If you're interested in clustering by these letters, as you point out recently, You can use the string function "split" to separate the string by a character.
(code above is changed accordingly to these new specification)
Example code for split function:

```py
    string = "sa_01_DF002"
    group = string.split('_')[2][0] # this is the letter you're interested in
    print("[0] =",string.split('_')[0])
    print("[1] =",string.split('_')[1])
    print("[2] =",string.split('_')[2])
```

you can use show the images, but you probably don't want to use it when you're reading too many pictures, so be careful

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your answer, but the output is not what i want, i add more details to my issue i look forward to your answer.

Comment: I simplified the code, now you have a dictionary with the name of the image, that contains a list of dimension 2. The first position is occupied by the image the second one is the group associated with this specific image

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to create a dictionary with each file type. Using the 7th character as the key to decide which file goes in which category, right?

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

arr = [x for x in os.listdir('.') if x.endswith(".png")]

d = defaultdict(list)
for file in arr:
    key = file[6]
    d[key].append(file)

print(d)
```

The variable `d` will now hold all the filenames in lists, where each list is characterized by a key. That key being the 7th character. Now if you need all files of type (for example) K, you can fetch them from `d` using `d['K']`.